# Nouveau failing to drive dual monitors on kernel 3.2.0-30

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, nouveau, dualhead

I have set up my system quite a while ago and even though nouveau has some quirks, I still prefer to use it to the nvidia drivers, because or randr.

After the latest kernel upgrades to version 3.2.0-30 and -31, it is unable to use dual head setup, or any external monitor for that matter. When I boot back into 3.2.0-29 everything is working fine. How to make the later kernels work with nouveau again?

Answer (score 1):

well, just for reference, this has helped:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common
```

It seems there was some sort of clash between nouvaeu and nvidia proprietary driver.